# Script that refreshes a website on all devices at the same time while developing

Tags: github

Some weeks ago I red about a script at github that will refresh a websites on all devices in the network at the same time while developing on it but I just can't remember the name.

I hope this answer doesn't count to the "this is not a research center forum" category but more I hope that someone might remember it we can share the answer for users that might looking for it too.

Before I get a thousand downvotes, please tell me if this a question at the wrong place (but where else then?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found it again:

https://github.com/marstall/shim

Answer (score 1):

[Meteor](http://www.meteor.com/) has been getting a lot of attention lately, but if all you need is a full page refresh, you could use any pub/sub framework, like [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/), and a few lines of javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. CodeKit or LiveReload already does the job for the browser inside the system but I'm still looking for a network option. I want to work on my iMac, save the code and the page will not only refresh on the iMac but also on the MacBook, iPad and iPhone too at the same time. These frameworks are looking way to large for this "simple" task. I'm still searching for that tool I once red about or any similar one.

Comment: Ok, finally found it. See my answer.